# Datagridview concurrency violations

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hello I am using the following code to update the DGV while validating:

```
        private void propertyInformationDataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (propertyInformationDataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty && e.ColumnIndex.ToString() != "3")
        {
            propertyInformationTableAdapter.Update((newCityCollectionDataSet)propertyInformationBindingSource.DataSource);
        }
    }
```

And this code to update the DGV and pass values to certain tables:

```
private void propertyInformationDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
     if (e.ColumnIndex.ToString() == "3")
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)propertyInformationDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3];


            DataGridViewRow row = propertyInformationDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewRow;

            System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRowView;
            newCityCollectionDataSet.PropertyInformationRow SelectedRow;

            SelectedRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)propertyInformationBindingSource.Current;
            SelectedRow = (newCityCollectionDataSet.PropertyInformationRow)SelectedRowView.Row;

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(checkCell.Value) == false && propertyInformationDataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            {
                DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

                var matchedCaseNumber = (from c in dc.GetTable<PropertyInformation>()
                                         where c.CaseNumberKey == SelectedRow.CaseNumberKey
                                         select c).SingleOrDefault();
                DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;

                reportsSent newReport = new reportsSent();
                newReport.CaseNumberKey = SelectedRow.CaseNumberKey;
                dc.reportsSents.InsertOnSubmit(newReport);
                matchedCaseNumber.DateFinished = saveNow;
                dc.SubmitChanges();

            }


        }
    }
```

What happens is when I click value finished or cellvalue 3 then click a different cell for instance cell value 0 on a different record I get an error.  I understand why I am getting the error but how would I go to prevent this?  Should I move the code from validating to click so that error does not occur or is there another way to deal with this?  The reason the error occurs is because I am updating with this :  `dc.SubmitChanges();` and then it updates again here:

```
if (propertyInformationDataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty && e.ColumnIndex.ToString() != "3")
        {
            propertyInformationTableAdapter.Update((newCityCollectionDataSet)propertyInformationBindingSource.DataSource);
        }
```

I am not sure how to force the right dataset to be updated after a case is finished.

Error is :

**Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.**

In the designer it shows up here:

```
 [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter")]
    public virtual int Update(newCityCollectionDataSet dataSet) {
        return this.Adapter.Update(dataSet, "PropertyInformation");
```

Thanks,

Kor

Comment: Always include the wording of the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly are you combining strongly typed datasets and LINQ to SQL? As you may have guessed, they're trying to update the same data, so the framework that comes in second is getting hit with a ConcurrencyViolation.

Comment: I understand what is occurring the question is how do I fix it?

Comment: Either use the same framework for everything, or reload each one from the DB every time the other updates the DB.

Comment: well I only know how to update a table with Linq to SQL so how would I do this?  The only value that needs to be updated is DateFinished to DateTime.Now() that is in the propertyInformation table.

Comment: newCityCollectionDataSet.PropertyInformationRow doesn't have a DateFinished property?

Comment: If I set SelectedRow.DateFinished = DateTime.Now; it does not check the checkbox.  It runs the code but ignores the checkbox I am going to guess because it is still trying to update 2 versions of the dataset at once. If i remove that line it works fine.

Comment: If you comment out the code for the DataContext and only set SelectedRow.DateFinished, then update with your TableAdapter - what happens?

Comment: Same thing.  The datacontext has no effect on the table that is populating the DGV.  What seems to be happening is the transaction is not occurring right then and is waiting.  What I ended up doing is updating the table adapter and then calling a method that refreshes the DGV (bindingsource.endedit, TableAdapter.fill and DGV.refresh).  One of my friends said I should try to wrap it in a trasaction block but I have no idea how that works as of yet.